# Dynamically creating comboboxes with the same Items by clicking on the button

Tags: c#

I have a button and a combobox. Then I'm clicking this button dynamically creating comboboxes.

This is code:

```
this.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Location = new Point(w, z), Width = 121, Height = 21});
```

How can I do, that by clicking on the button will be create comboboxes with the same items?

With the one combobox I know how, but how can I do with the dynamically created comboboxes, that by clicking on the button will be create dynamically comboboxes with the same 7 elements?

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable

x-editable is built around creating new elements within a page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question (sorry if i was wrong), you may want to try this:

1. Declare 2 global variable like this

   ```
       private string[] elements = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" }; // Sample 7 item to put inside of your dropdownlist
       private int click = 0; // Initial value of click, will increase 1 after each click.
   ```
2. Then on `button1_click` event, put this code.

   ```
       int w = 100, z = 100; // Initial position
       this.click++; // Click value increase everytime you click

       ComboBox c;  

       this.Controls.Add(c = new ComboBox() // Create new combobox
       {
           Location = new Point(w, z + (this.click * 30)), // Each time you click, position on x-axis will stay and y-axis will increase by `click` multiply by 30 (you can change this '30' value)
           Width = 121,
           Height = 21,

       });

       for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++) // Loop 7 times
       {
           c.Items.Add(this.elements[i]);
       }
   ```
3. I hope this answer your question :)